# PHPExcel: How to check whether a XLS file is valid or not?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using `PHPExcel 1.7.8` to read `.xls` files, uploaded by a radom user. All is working properly with a valid `.xls` file, but now I wanted to make some tests with invalid files to check if the program displays good error messages.

So I took a `.csv` file, and renamed it with `.xls` (without converting anything, just changing the name) to the end, just to check...
Broken! :)

```
DOM ELEMENT: HTML
DOM ELEMENT: BODY
DOM ELEMENT: P
START OF PARAGRAPH: 
END OF PARAGRAPH:
FLUSH CELL: A1 => block,date,hour...

array
  1 =>
    array
      'A' => string  'block,date,hour...' (length=2777)

{"step":"error","errors":[],"warnings":[]}
```

Like you can see, there's an error message displaying, I didn't ask for that, and then the JSON that I usually write.

It happens on this line :

```
<?php
echo "Loading file\n";
try {
    if (!($objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('path'))) {
        echo "Failed\n";
        return;
        // ...
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception !';
}
echo "Done\n";
```

And this code displays:

```
Loading file
/!\ ERROR MESSAGE ABOVE /!\
Done
```

My question is, is there a way with PHPExcel or anything else to **check whether a file is a valid XLS file** before I try to parse it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each reader in PHPExcel has a canRead() method that validates the file passed in to the read is of the appropriate format for that reader - the method returns a simple boolean True or False. A return of True from a call to the canRead() method of the PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5 class will confirm that the file can be read by that reader, irrespective of the file extension.

The IOFactory identify() method uses this call, testing against the Readers for each supported format in turn until it gets a true return from the canRead() call. The IOFactory load() method, in it's turn, uses identify() to determine which Reader should be used for the specified file.

The ability to verify a filetype (without depending on the file extension which can often be misleading) is particularly useful when you want to set additional arguments for the reader.

The fallback from identify()/load() is slightly less satisfactory: if canRead() returns false for all other Readers, then the file is treated as a CSV.

Comment: I'm using `load()` and I'm checking the return value, but with this corrupt file, instead of returning false, it returns true and display the error above (I would rather expect it to **`throw`** an error, not to `echo` it)

Comment: PHPExcel throws exceptions.... you should try wrapping your load() in a try/catch block, as recommended in the manual

Comment: I just edited my post with my code, none exception is caught but the error appears...

Comment: Correct - this won't throw an error... load() calls identify(); identify() calls the canRead() method for each Reader.... the fallback is to treat the file as a CSV, as I said in my reply

Comment: As I said, you can use the IOFactory identify() method to see what format PHPExcel thinks the file is, or instantiate the reader that you think should be used and then call the canRead() method to test the boolean return. This is the documented behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Mark! I'll give it a try! And sorry if I missed that in the documentation.

Comment: Wrapping in an exception won't work, when you rename a non-xls file with .xls extension, the reader only throws a warning, which can be catched with `try/catch` block.

Comment: @MarkBaker I think there is something wrong with the logic of PHPExcel here....if I load .jpg file, then identify()/load() decides that it is CSV?? Am I missing something or this is really stupid?

Comment: @Andrew There is no definitive test for a csv file, so PHPExcel treats any file that fails all other recognition tests as a csv.... if you can suggest a decent test to recognise a csv file, then I'm happy to take a look at it... see my answer, an my previous reply comments to this question

Comment: @MarkBaker Instead of checking if file is CSV, you should check if file is Not CSV and then return appropriate response. So try parsing first line of "CSV" file, if it fails - return false from canRead() or throw exception, etc. Because now I am uploading non-text files and they are not stopped/not handled appropriately by my validation...not good.

Comment: So to check if it's a NOT CSV, I need to check for every possible alternative; all those hundreds of different non-csv options that are available..... that's a lot of work it will be incredibly slow.... If people are uploading jpg files instead of spreadsheet files, you really should be trapping for such things in your own code, not simply complaining about the behaviour of PHPExcel.... the PHPExcel test is to try and identify what reader should be used to parse the file that it has been given, it is not a filetype validator for all filetypes

Comment: How about just parse?  something like fgetcsv(). If it can read first line, then it's valid file, if it can't - return false.

Comment: fgetcsv will return a valid response for any file type

Comment: Even for .avi? And what it will return then?

Comment: Try it and see..... fgetcsv will read the appropriate number of bytes (or to a first newline character) then split that line on commas..... if there's no newlines or commas, then you'll get the appropriate number of bytes in array element 0

Answer (score 20):

Even if it's more than a year question, I still find it cumbersome to figure it out how to deal with this issue, I'll try to post my answer here.

If using try/catch block doesn't work *(in my case, I renamed a jpg file to xls and the error handler doesn't work, instead of throwing error, invalid file just throws a warning)*, you can consider a manual checking using `canRead()` as Mark said, here's an example of how to use this function.

If you know what your filetypes are, you can define it manually and check against them:

```
$valid = false;
$types = array('Excel2007', 'Excel5');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($type);
    if ($reader->canRead($file_path)) {
        $valid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($valid) {
  // TODO: load file
  // e.g. PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_path)
} else {
  // TODO: show error message
}
```

Hope this help anyone with the same problem.