# Upload only Excel files in PHP

Tags: php

How do I allow only excel files to be uploaded? Here is my code and this work fine.

```
    $target_dir = 'uploads/';
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filepath"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filepath"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
```

Comment: you find all possible extensions of excel files, put them in array then check if $imageFileType matches anything in that array, if it does, then allow upload ?

Comment: one thing to be careful of, i d say, would be that users can just change extension to xls and pass your upload test

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13626842/6468413

Comment: can you give me an example sir

Comment: @JanKlenschAsentista SO is not code service provider.

Answer (score 0):

There's no foolproof way to do this, short of trying to parse the uploaded file. You can use `$_FILES["filepath"]["type"]` to check the browser-provided MIME type, but this may not be accurate, especially with something like an Excel file.